# How dynamically set variables on Cron?

Tags: php, shell, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to make a cron file to be placed in /etc/croon. d. My problem is I don't want keep this file updated, so I'm looking for a way to get the software version dynamically from a file. 
I have few other variables, but for now I think the problem is with `$ (cat /software/VERSION)`, it works very well in shell script but not on croon.

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=SOME_STRING
VERSION=$(cat /software/VERSION)
HOME=/var/www/scripts/$VERSION/cron
CRON_LOG_DIR=/var/www/scripts/logs

*/2 *   *   *   *   root    cd  $HOME & php -f $HOME/do_something.php $APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT  >> $CRON_LOG/something.log
```

This is the output on cron log:

```
(root) CMD (cd  $HOME & php -f $HOME/do_something.php $APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT >> $CRON_LOG/something.log)
(CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/srv/www/tdp/public/$VERSION/backend/cron): No such file or directory
```

Comment: the cron could call a shell (or php) script. its not a place to put programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron table is *not* a shell script! You cannot put variables there.

You have to call a script from the cron and do the logic there.

If you really **have** to set environment variables in cron, you can do it like this

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   root    SHELL=/bin/bash VARIABLE=something cd  $HOME & php -f $HOME/do_something.php $APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT  >> $CRON_LOG/something.log
```

But it might not work and you might make a mistake (I am not 100% sure I made the syntax right; it's not easy and it's not necessary).

You should put as little logic to cron as possible.

Also, you should not edit the cron file directly; use `crontab -e` instead, it will check if you made correct syntax.

So you should do

```
*/2 *   *   *   *   user    /home/user/your-script.sh
```

and set the variables *in your script*. (You also shouldn't run programs as root if it's possible.)

Comment: Thanks!

But how can I edit a /etc/cron.d/myfile with  crontab -e ?